# mysql create table with long string data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I was making online forum. I made writing function. My writing form is devided into title and content. Normally, it works well. But if I type a little bit longer in content, error occurs. I use mysql and sequelize.
Here is error message
[image]
and here is my code

```
router.post('/', isLoggedIn, upload2.none(), async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const post = await Post.create({
            title: req.body.title.toLowerCase(),
            content: req.body.editordata,
            img: req.body.url,
            UserId: req.user.id,
        });
        res.redirect('/');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error); 
        next(error);
    }
});
```

(code which error occures)

and my post module looks likes this

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = class Post extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        return super.init({
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        content: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(20000),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        img: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(250),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        }, {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: true,
        underscored: false,
        modelName: 'Post',
        tableName: 'posts',
        paranoid: false,
        charset: 'utf8mb4',
        collate: 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        });
    }

    static associate(db) {
        db.Post.belongsTo(db.User);
        db.Post.belongsToMany(db.Hashtag, { through: 'PostHashtag' });
    }
};
```

Is there any way to save long data in table?

I tried increasing number in here.
(post module)

```
content: {
    type: Sequelize.**STRING(20000),**
    allowNull: false,
},
```

It was still same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  [Sequelize.TEXT('long')](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/other-data-types/)

```
content: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT('long'),
    allowNull: false,
},
```

**LONGTEXT**

A `TEXT` column with a maximum length of `4,294,967,295` or `4GB (232 - 1)` in bytes. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multi-byte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is stored using a four-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

Ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/longtext/

Comment: Minor correction: the maximum length is 4GB in bytes, not characters. How many characters that stores depends on how many multibyte characters you use, but it's 4GB regardless.

Comment: I dropped my mysql table and followed your solution. And it works well! thank you!!